# Yii not redirecting properly with the CController::redirect() function

Tags: php, yii

In a yii site I am creating I have a page with the url `http://localhost/administrator/restaurant/list`
which shows the list of restaurants in a tabular format along with a delete button. The delete button points to `http://localhost/administrator/restaurant/delete/<id>`.

The `actionDelete` of my controller is as follows :

```
public function actionDelete(){
        $model = Restaurants::model()->findByAttributes(
                                        array(
                                            'id'=>$_GET['id'],
                                            'clientId'=>Yii::app()->user->clientId
                                        ));
        $model->delete();
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success',Yii::t('error','Restaurant has been deleted successfully'));
        $this->redirect('restaurant/list',true);
    }
```

But on clicking the delete button, the row is getting deleted successfully from the database but instead of redirecting to `http://localhost/administrator/restaurant/list` the page is redirecting to `http://localhost/administrator/restaurant/delete/restaurant/list` and showing an error. Is there something wrong with the way I implemented the redirect function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use array routing instead:

```
$this->redirect(array('restaurant/list'), true);
```

---

Using GET for deleting is a very bad idea because browsers can prefetch links before you even click them. You should use POST for any scenario like this.